# Changing Size of IconButton in React

Tags: reactjs, react-native

The code below creates a grid of icon buttons.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import Background from '../components/Background'
import { Alert, View, FlatList, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native'
import { IconButton } from "@react-native-material/core";
import Icon from "@expo/vector-icons/MaterialCommunityIcons";

const Item = ({ item }) => {
    return <View style={styles.item}>{item.icon}</View>;
};

export default function HomeScreen() {
    return (
        <Background>
            <View style={styles.list}>
                <FlatList
                    data={itemData}
                    numColumns={3}
                    renderItem={Item}
                    keyExtractor={(item) => item.alt}
                />
            </View>

        </Background>
    )
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    list: {
        marginHorizontal: "auto",
        width: 300,
        borderRadius: 10,

    },
    item: {
        flex: 1,
        maxWidth: "33.33%", // 100% devided by the number of rows you want
        alignItems: "center",
    }
})

const itemData = [
    {
        icon: (
            <IconButton
                icon={props => <Icon name="food" {...props} />} /> //needs food 

        ),
    },
    {
        icon: (
            <IconButton
                icon={props => <Icon name="bed" {...props} />} /> //needs sleep
        ),
    },
    {
        icon: (
            <IconButton
                icon={props => <Icon name="glass-wine" {...props} />} />
        ),
    },

]
```

I want to change the size of the icon buttons in the flat list. I tried adding `size = {50}` to `styles.item` but it doesn't actually change the size.  I've tried a few other things but the IconButtons seem resistant to any size argument.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try passing the `size` prop to the `icon` prop of the `IconButton` component?
e,g,

```
const itemData = [
{
    icon: (
        <IconButton
            icon={props => <Icon name="food" {...props} size={50} />} />
    ),
},
{
    icon: (
        <IconButton
            icon={props => <Icon name="bed" {...props} size={50} />} />
    ),
},
{
    icon: (
        <IconButton
            icon={props => <Icon name="glass-wine" {...props} size={50} />} />
    ),
},
```

];

By setting the size prop to 50, you should see an increase in the size of the icons in the grid.

Also, you can manipulate the size of the icon button container by adding `height` and `width`
e.g.

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
list: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    width: 300,
    borderRadius: 10,
},
item: {
    flex: 1,
    maxWidth: "33.33%", // 100% divided by the number of rows you want
    alignItems: "center",
    height: 80, // adjust as per your desired size
    width: 80, // adjust as per your desired size
},
```

});